# RMLSE validation between rpart model and test set showing Na and zero

Tags: r, r-caret

I am seeking a little help as I have hit a wall.
I have trained a model (CART) with a train dataset and am looking to validate the accuracy of the model with RMLSE on a test set.
I have the following:

```
data.frame':    5463 obs. of  15 variables:
$ Start_date: chr  "2011-01-20 02:00:00" "2011-01-20 05:00:00" "2011-01-20  06:00:00"
$ Season    : Factor w/ 4 levels "spring","summer",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
$ Holiday   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Not","Holiday": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Workingday: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Weather   : Factor w/ 4 levels "Clear","Cloudy",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2..
 $ Temp      : num  10.66 9.84 9.02 9.02 9.02 ...
 $ Humidity  : int  56 60 60 55 55 52 48 45 42 45 ...
 $ Windspeed : num  0 15 15 15 19 ...
 $ Count     : num  1 1 1 8 18 6 3 4 5 3 ...
 $ Date      : chr  "2011-01-20" "2011-01-20" "2011-01-20" "2011-01-20" ...
 $ Hour      : Factor w/ 24 levels "00","01","02",..: 3 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 .
 $ Year      : chr  "2011" "2011" "2011" "2011" ...
 $ Month     : chr  "01" "01" "01" "01" ...
 $ Weekday   : Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
 $ Hour_Bin  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ temp_Bin  : num  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ year_Bin  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The predicted values is vector of:

```
    Named num [1:5463] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
   - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5463] "9266" "9267" "9268" "9269" ...
```

I have used the function:

```
Evaluate_Model <- function (test, pred) {
return(sqrt(1/nrow(test)*sum((log(pred+1)-log(test$Count+1))^2)))
}
```

and also tried the matrix package

```
library('Metrics')
rmsle(test$Count, pred)
```

when I try to get the Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error, I am returned either [0] or [Na].
I gone through the process of converting the count variable to different data types, and also tried putting the prediction into a dataframe and evaluate it from their. 
I have also trained a model with one attribute and tried to evaluate these models, but am still hetting the same result.
My target variable (count) and the other attributes have zero values, but these are real values, not na's.
IS it the training of the algorithm, the data types???
Any help would be appreciated.

A sample of the model code:

```
model3 <- rpart(Count~Month+Temp, data = train)
# round prediction
pred <- round(predict(model3, newdata = test))
Evaluate_Model(test, pred)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that your predicted values are characters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pascal, I thought it might be the value types, however I have tried running mini models with  different types and still get the same.

Comment: Also, variables `Year` and  `Month` are character vectors. They probably should be integer.

Comment: I don't think its actually the values types within the predictive model. I have tried predicting 'count' with only 'num', 'int' and 'factor'. I am still getting the same results. I am open to correction though as I am not that experienced.

Comment: Do you get the same for examples in the help files?

Comment: Hi @RomanLuštrik, I tried it on a toy dataset and also on another dataset and I am getting the same, [0] and [NaN]. I am fairly sure I have the packages installed (didn't get any errors). Are you thinking the problem is not with the code but somewhere else?

Comment: Assuming the toy examples from help files work, the culprit may be narrowed down to the code at hand (some way or another).